# How to define a type for a static property on a constructor function

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with typescript throwing an error when I try to assign a static property to a constructor function: `Property 'wheels' does not exist on type '() => void'.` How can I tell typescript that my `Car` object can have `wheels` property?

```js
function Car() {
    // do something
}

Car.wheels = 4 // throws: Property 'wheels' does not exist on type '() => void'.

const audi = new Car()
```

Above snippet can be tested on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html

Comment: Why don't you define a class, with a static property? `class Car { static wheels = 4; }`

Comment: it's the pattern we followed in my company from before classes were a thing and we have hundreds of cases like this and I'm trying to introduce typescript without rewriting every constructor function to a class.

The above example is a reproduction example, not a real use case (these are much more complicated).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function Car() {
    // do something
}

namespace Car { 
    export let wheels = 4
}

const audi = new Car()
```

See the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-namespaces-with-classes-functions-and-enums).

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of type acrobatics, renaming and multiple variables you can use a [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html) to achieve what you want:

```
function Car_() {
    // do something
};

type TCar = typeof Car_ & { wheels: number };
const Car = (Car_ as TCar);

Car.wheels = 4; // throws: Property 'wheels' does not exist on type '() => void'.

const audi = new Car()
```

The solution suggested by @MattMcCutchen looks more legit though.